# Dplyr add column to data frame based on specific value of grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame containing number of page views per week for various users. It looks like this:

```
Userid week views
eerr   24   1
dd     24   2
dd     25   1
...
```

I want to plot average page views per week. However, I want to group users by the number of page views they had in the first week so that I can plot separate trajectories for users with different activity levels. I can get the first week for each user by doing

```
weekdf = df %>% group_by(Userid) %>% mutate(firstweek = min(week))
```

But I can't figure out how to group by the value of views in the row with that first week. I tried using a user-defined function within summarise, which seemed to work, but it never terminated, and I can see why - it has to recalculate everything many times.

```
getoffset <- function(week, Userid,minweekdf)
{
 minweek = minweekdf[minweekdf$Userid == Userid,2] 
 offsetweek = week - minweek
 return(offsetweek)
}

offsetdf = df %>% group_by(Userid, week) %>% summarise(offsetweek = getoffset(week, Userid, minweek))
```

How can I do this, preferably in dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

`df %>% group_by(Userid) %>% arrange(week) %>% mutate(fv = first(views) )`

and then you can group by fv

Comment: The arrange --> first trick is brilliant! Thanks! And thanks for working out what I was trying to ask - I had a hard time formulating the question.

Comment: Or `df %>% group_by(Userid) %>% mutate(fv = first(views, week))`